# How to create a comment with data from endpoint?

Tags: github, github-actions, github-api

At my company, we have a CLI which allows our customers to upload data to our backend solution. The CLI runs on PR changes within a job. Let's assume the uploaded data looks like this:

```
{
    name: "John",
    age: 20,
}
```

Once the upload is completed, I'd like to create a comment on the PR with to following body:
`John is 20 years old`.

I've found the following ways to do this:

- GitHub App (a bot)
- GitHub OAuth App
- Personal Access Token
- `GITHUB_TOKEN`

### GitHub App

The GitHub App needs to do the following things:

- Fetch the data via a user-specific API key
- Create a comment

I already created a comment via a bot, but I have no clue how to fetch the data.

As far as my understanding goes, I'd like other users to be able to install this GitHub app from the marketplace to work out of the box. From the [ProBot Docs](https://probot.github.io/) I understand that the bot operates on a webhook basis. Meaning I need to subscribe to a 'job completed' event (not sure if that's the correct name but I think you get the idea) and then fetch the data via a user-specific API we are providing on our platform. However, I see no way for the user of our App to configure an API key (or any form of secret) so the bot can make authenticated requests to our endpoints.

I'd prefer to use GitHub App because the comment coming from the bot would have our company branding and also an indicator that this comment has been created by the integration.

### OAuth App

I already tested this by using Postman, however, the comment looks like it's coming from a specific user. Therefore, it has no company branding and it's not clear that an integration created the comment. However, the great part is that we could integrate this with our application, so our backend could create the comment once the data is received.

What I like about this approach is that we also need to implement such a feature for GitLab, Azure, etc, and using OAuth likely scales well with the other providers in comparison to the GitHub app, which is GitHub-specific.

### Personal Access Token

Works pretty much like the OAuth App, but instead of our backend creating the comment, the comment is created by the CLI (and the access token is passed into the CLI). However, I think this approach is a bit sketchy.

### [GITHUB_TOKEN](https://docs.github.com/en/actions/security-guides/automatic-token-authentication)

While I haven't tried this yet, I assume that the token has limited but sufficient permissions to create a comment. As of now, I don't know what the comment will look like, but I think we can rather safely pass this into the CLI to create the comment from there. Since the permissions are limited and the token is invalidated after the workflow I see limited risk for the user of our CLI (and services).

Edit: The comment is coming from the `github-actions` bot, which is not the branding we are looking for, but it's clear that the comment has been created by the integration.

## Questions

- What's the best way to accomplish what I am trying?
- Is there any way I can make this work with GitHub Apps (aka bots)?

Comment: Regarding the branding for the comment, you could create a new service user (as an account in your org that would be used just for that on GitHub, using its PAT in the workflow). Using OAuth or tokens seems a good solution to me, I would choose the easiest option regarding how to extract the datas and commit the message (using a script or shell commands in the workflow).